# Can I install Ubuntu while using a ASUS H110m-a motherboard?

Tags: system-installation, asus

The motherboard is ASUS H110M-A, and I want to install Ubuntu. After selecting the language for creating and installing USB for booting, press ??? button and ?? as shown in the picture. When I tried to select the English language while installing Ubuntu, I got the same error.
What should I do?

[image: IMG:]

[image]

Comment: oh..!!! i try this mathod tomorrow! thank you so much

Comment: now i insert some instruct 'sudo dmraid -a n' 
but.... no raid disks